# Parcel 2 Dev Server router fallback

Tags: parceljs

i prepared some code where i start the parcel 2 dev server with 2 different entrypoints. The following routes are working:

http://0.0.0.0:3000/index-1.html
http://0.0.0.0:3000/index-2.html

The problem i currently have is when i type another not existing route like http://0.0.0.0:3000/test then it's redirecting me to the first entrypoint (index-1.html).

Is there any way to configure it to show a 404 status instead?

This is my code to run the server:

```
const { Parcel } = require('@parcel/core')

let bundler = new Parcel({
  entries: [
    'src/index-1.html',
    'src/index-2.html'
  ],
  mode: 'development',
  logLevel: 'warn',
  defaultTargetOptions: {
    publicUrl: '/',
    distDir: './dist',
    shouldScopeHoist: false,
    sourceMaps: true,
    includeNodeModules: true,
    shouldOptimize: false,
    engines: {
      browsers: ['ie >= 11']
    }
  },
  shouldAutoInstall: true,
  shouldDisableCache: false,
  shouldContentHash: true,
  serveOptions: { publicUrl: '/', host: '0.0.0.0', port: 3000, https: false },
  hmrOptions: { port: 3000, host: '0.0.0.0' }
})

bundler.watch((err, event) => {
  if (err) {
    // fatal error
    throw err
  }

  if (event.type === 'buildSuccess') {
    let bundles = event.bundleGraph.getBundles()
    console.log(`✨ Built ${bundles.length} bundles in ${event.buildTime}ms!`);
  } else if (event.type === 'buildFailure') {
    console.log(event.diagnostics)
  }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe not the best solution, but i needed to fix it somehow today: I created a proxyrc file in my root folder with the following code:

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware')
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

module.exports = app => {
  let brokenPaths = []

  const filterBrokenPaths = pathname => {
    return brokenPaths.includes(pathname)
  }

  app.use('/', (req, res, next) => {
    const dir = path.join(__dirname, 'dist')
    let filename = req.originalUrl.split('?')[0]

    if (!fs.existsSync(path.join(dir, filename))) {
      if (!brokenPaths.includes(req.originalUrl)) {
        brokenPaths.push(req.originalUrl)
      }
    }

    next()
  })

  app.use(
    createProxyMiddleware(filterBrokenPaths, {
      target: `http://${ hostname }:${ port }`,
      pathRewrite () {
        return '/404'
      },
      logLevel: "warn"
    })
  )
}
```

In this case i check on every request if the path is also existing in my public folder, otherwise i redirect to a 404 page, which is defined in a separate express app.

Comment: Where does `hostname` and `port` comes from?